# Uploading a file from a Java program to a Server

Tags: java, python, file-upload, bottle

I want to upload a zip file from my java application to a server which is running the Bottle web framework.

I have previously used a django server and I uploaded small files by converting them to binary data and then sending that through a post request.

I am not sure if this is the best idea for this project as the zip files will be between 1-10 mb.

Is it still ideal to convert to binary and then send the data or is there another method that would be recommended.

Comment: If your zip file isn't binary it isn't going to work. Unless you're talking about some text encoding for transfer (which will increase the file size).

Comment: not sure what you mean by if the zip file isn't binary. Everything is binary. I just have to read the file as binary and I have the file. I was planning on reading it as binary then maybe encoding it with base64 to make the data less.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading large files can lead to this dreadful experience that after uploading 99% your connection breaks down and you have to start over.

When uploading a large file from an application (which seems to be your case) to a server via HTTP, I would prefer the following way:

Let your application divide the file in small chunks of some reasonable size. Tag these junks with a serial number. POST to your server that this connection will start uploading a large file and send the meta data (filename, etc). Then start POSTing the chunks.

When the server receives a chunk, he should acknowledge this to the client.

On the server side you need to implement the logic to keep track of transmitted and missing chunks and then re-assemble the chunked file.

Just my two cents.

Or let the server decide which chunk it needs. Sample dialogue:

```
Client: I will upload "test.zip" in 4 chunks.
Server: Go ahead. Please send chunk 1.
Client: I am sending chunk 1 with checksum X.
Server: Thank you, checksum is OK. Please send chunk 2.
Client: I am sending chunk 2 with checksum Y.
Server: Thank you, checksum is bad. Please send chunk 2.
Client: I am sending chunk 2 with checksum Y.
Server: Thank you, checksum is OK. Please send chunk 3.
Client: I am sending chunk 3 with checksum Z.
Server: Thank you, checksum is OK. Please send chunk 4.
Client: I am sending chunk 4 with checksum A.
Server: Thank you, checksum is OK. Have a nice day.
```

Starting with this it is easy to implement re-transmission of missing chunks if the connection breaks down.